# I cannot get my MKRoute to show up on a MapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I am trying to add an MKOverlay (my MKRoute) to my MapView, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. This is pretty sloppy because I'm experimenting with it before I implement it in my app.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    var geocoder:CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var location:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 38, longitude: -77)
    var next:CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 38.9, longitude: -77.61)
    var locMark:MKPlacemark?
    var destMark:MKPlacemark?
    var manager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var source:MKMapItem?
    var destination:MKMapItem?
    var request:MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    var directions:MKDirections = MKDirections()
    var directionsResponse:MKDirectionsResponse = MKDirectionsResponse()
    var route:MKRoute! = MKRoute()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.map.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        let latDelt = 0.05
        let lonDelt = 0.05

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latDelt, longitudeDelta: lonDelt)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), span: span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


        map.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite


        locMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)
        destMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(next.coordinate.latitude, next.coordinate.longitude), addressDictionary: nil)

        source = MKMapItem(placemark: locMark)
        destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destMark)

        request.setSource(source)
        request.setDestination(destination)
        request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler { (response:MKDirectionsResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                self.directionsResponse = response!
                self.route = self.directionsResponse.routes[0] as! MKRoute
                self.map.addOverlay(self.route.polyline)
            } else {
                println(error)
            }
        }

        func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

            if overlay is MKPolyline {
                var pr = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
                pr.strokeColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                pr.lineWidth = 5
                return pr
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I don't get any errors printed, but not route shows up on the map at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `rendererForOverlay` function is *nested* inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //your viewDidLoad code is here...

    //rendererForOverlay is declared here inside viewDidLoad...
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        ...
    }

}  // <-- closing brace of viewDidLoad
```

Because of this, the `rendererForOverlay` function is hidden from the map view and it does not call it resulting in no overlay displaying.

To fix this, move the `rendererForOverlay` function outside `viewDidLoad` so that it's visible to the rest of the class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //your viewDidLoad code is here...

}  // <-- closing brace of viewDidLoad

//put rendererForOverlay here outside viewDidLoad...
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I could literally cry right now in joy. Actually, I am crying a bit. You solved it.  Now I'm not 100% concrete with the concept, but I can work off this working code. Thank you SO much, you ended my 4 day Google binge.